# How to immediately stop the automatic compositing after adding a unconnected node?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I just added a random node tab without connected it to any output node, but the compositing automatically starts. It has wasted a lot of computing resource for this unnecessary compositing.

[image]

**My Goal:**
I want the compositing to only start if the added node is connected to an output node. How do I do that please?

Comment: Hello ! Adding a node automatically triggers an update of the compositing pipeline, I think this is a known limitation of the system.

Comment: The only workaround I know is to disable _Use Nodes_ in the _Compositor_ and only activate it when you need the result. But this can also lead to having to refresh something when you enable it again to re-composite, like toggling _Alpha_ on/off in the _Composite_ node for example.